# SBCL optimization: Can we compile an efficient population count for bit-vectors?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, common-lisp, x86-64, sbcl

SBCL, the Lisp implementation I use, knows to compile `(logcount x)` to the x86-64 `POPCNT` instruction if `x` is typeable as a sufficiently short `unsigned-byte`.  Presuming that a `simple-bit-vector` gets stored by SBCL in a word-aligned continuous memory segment, how might one get the compiler to perform a similarly optimized population count thereon?  The standard doesn't provide a `(bit-vector-logcount)` (an odd omission, in my opinion); nor does it allow me to `(coerce)` to a `fixnum`.

An intentionally naïve implementation is as follows; note that there is also a [Ω(1)-time one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10445818/12808416), while the Harley-Seal technique [1] may be a better choice for large vectors.  But this is simple enough for an optimizing compiler to spot the intent:

```
(defun bit-vector-unsigned-logcount (x)
  "Not worrying about negative interpretations of X."
  (declare (type (simple-bit-vector 32) x)
           (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (loop for b across x
        count (not (zerop b))))
```

On SBCL 2.0.1 I get this:

```
; disassembly for BIT-VECTOR-UNSIGNED-LOGCOUNT
; Size: 67 bytes. Origin: #x52B88079                          ; BIT-VECTOR-UNSIGNED-LOGCOUNT
; 79:       31D2             XOR EDX, EDX
; 7B:       31C0             XOR EAX, EAX
; 7D:       31C9             XOR ECX, ECX
; 7F:       EB2C             JMP L1
; 81:       660F1F840000000000 NOP
; 8A:       660F1F440000     NOP
; 90: L0:   488BD0           MOV RDX, RAX
; 93:       48D1FA           SAR RDX, 1
; 96:       480FA35301       BT QWORD PTR [RBX+1], RDX
; 9B:       19D2             SBB EDX, EDX
; 9D:       83E202           AND EDX, 2
; A0:       4883C002         ADD RAX, 2
; A4:       4885D2           TEST RDX, RDX
; A7:       7404             JEQ L1
; A9:       4883C102         ADD RCX, 2
; AD: L1:   4883F840         CMP RAX, 64
; B1:       7CDD             JL L0
; B3:       488BD1           MOV RDX, RCX
; B6:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; B9:       F8               CLC
; BA:       5D               POP RBP
; BB:       C3               RET
```

I will give the [SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Miscellaneous-Efficiency-Issues) a chance to speak.

> If your system's performance is suffering because of some construct which could in principle be compiled efficiently, but which the SBCL compiler can't in practice compile efficiently, consider writing a patch to the compiler and submitting it for inclusion in the main sources.

I suspect I am facing such a case, and I'd be pleased to oblige, but I know almost nothing about VOP hacking beyond having looked at the articles by Paul Khuong [here](http://pvk.ca/Blog/2013/04/13/starting-to-hack-on-sbcl/) and [here](https://pvk.ca/Blog/2014/08/16/how-to-define-new-intrinsics-in-sbcl/).

`x86-64/arith.lisp` defines a couple of VOPs, `unsigned-byte-64-count` and `positive-fixnum-count`, which look as though they could be repurposed for the job if we could tease the `bit-vector` apart.

---

[1] Muła, W., Kurz, N., & Lemire, D. (2017). [*Faster Population Counts Using AVX2 Instructions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07612). The Computer Journal, 61(1), 111–120. doi: 10.1093/comjnl/bxx046

Comment: For CPUs that don't support the `popcnt` instruction, this doesn't look good!  `BT mem, reg` is quite slow.  This looks like it's looping `i += 2` and testing a bit at `i/2`, recomputing those offsets every time through the loop, as well as branching on the FLAGS result of `bt` after putting it in a register and back into FLAGS.  This is really bad, and would benefit a lot from some kind of peephole optimization that can recognize such a bit count operation and use `popcnt`, or a good bithack as a fallback like libgcc's helper func.  (Or over large arrays, AVX2 `vpshufb` for SIMD popcount).

Comment: For large vectors, https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount/ has a variety of implementations, with benchmarks on modern HW.  Fun fact: for C / C++ compilers, clang can auto-vectorize `__builtin_popcountll` into a nibble-LUT (avx2-lookup) loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That repo is by the chaps from the 'Faster Population Counts' paper, I see.   And the other one _it_ links to, https://github.com/kimwalisch/libpopcnt, would also be a useful reference... if I could figure out how to write SBCL intrinsics!

Answer (score 2):

Can sb-kernel:%vector-raw-bits be the missing piece?

```
(logcount (sb-kernel:%vector-raw-bits #*100101010 0))
```

-> 4

```
(disassemble (compile () (lambda (a) (logcount (sb-kernel:%vector-raw-bits a    0)))))
```

-> (...) POPCNT (...)

How to find: check, e.g., `bit-and`, and jump to definition (M-. in sly/slime repl), select the `deftransform` for `simple-bit-vectors`.

Needless to say this is implementation specific and needs some care to be safe, but so are vops.